# 4iiii powermeter failure - anyone been able to fix this 'class failure'?

Tags: failure

Unfortunately, I have one of the failing 4iiii powermeters, which suddenly starts massively misreading the watts (over-reading) and is unable to calibrate. 
I have been in contact with 4iii, who sent me the instruction here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1elLsrGRZ4P_SjmzXphXSytmUv4VKTv2jeye-riXkGUA/mobilebasic. 
Unfortunately, it did not fix the problem. 
Since there is no warranty left, I am really left with a problem here. It has only been used on my summer bike and not a whole lot.

So, I would really love to hear, if anyone knows of a fix to this problem, which seems to be so common that it comes close to being a class failure.

Thanks!

Morten

Comment: Have you replaced both batteries? (If you did, remove and wait a minute before putting back in.) Is the firmware up to date? Unpairing and re-pairing may help  I had similar trouble with Powertap pedals where waiting to put in the batteries seemed to do some kind of reset.

Comment: Thanks. Yew. New battery - there is only one - latest firmware. 

I would really love to hear from anyone who has been able to fix this issue. 

Morten